# Any SSDs with USER PROGRAMMABLE Cache Configuration Capability?

Tags: ssd

We all know that SSDs are marching from SLC, to MLC, QLC, PLC generation by generation.  We know that this involves greater quantization of threshold voltage levels and increased complexity-driven-latency per read operation across generations, and it impacts overall lifetime durability as well. (Nonetheless overall speed of SSDs is rising despite the packing of more bits per cell.)

Given that the underlying silicon architecture for each cell/bit across generations is the same floating gate mosfet, and given that SSDs rely very advantageously on the CS concept of "caching" to provide their mind blowing speed and dynamism,  which caching is implemented within SSD firmware by simply accessing a certain proportion of the SSD's memory cells in SLC fashion (rather than MLC or what have you)....

My question: are there any SSDs on the market which allow the User to set the SSD firmware to treat any specified percentage of the SSDs memory as purely SLC cache? (So if the user wanted, they could buy a 250GB SSD and set the firmware to treat the whole drive (100%) as a 60GB SLC if they choose to do so.)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you find a source that supports the idea that a QLC NAND chip is even capable of switching between multiple modes (QLC/SLC)? It seems like a chip that could be used in multiple modes like this would be extremely complex and not something you'd want to hand over to the user to play around with. A specific chip or portion of the memory may be fixed as SLC just to ensure it is reliable, or else you could end up moving the cache to a section that doesn't perform as well.

Comment: I'm not saying configurable on the fly. I'm talking about user configuration by firmware per user's choice.  it's a user set-up thing. maybe from bios?

Comment: OK, the same reasoning is even more applicable to the firmware. That stuff is extremely complex and they don't want users to be playing with it. The BIOS is not the right place for settings like that even if they did exist, you would either have to build a new firmware and flash it to the SSD (yikes) or use an application that talks to the SSD from the OS. But nothing like that exists as far as I've seen.

Comment: There is ONE vendor, Enmotus, that sells a "software-driven caching" product. 
https://www.anandtech.com/show/15442/enmotus-midrive-rethinking-slc-caching-for-qlc-ssds